# python import module from a parent directory

Tags: python-2.7, module

I have the following structure and I am using the below to import functions 
( i.e basically importing a module from a parent directory)

```
from demo import sayHello
```

It works but in Pycharm it says unresolved reference. Should I continue or should I use the relative path like below, then I get no warnings

```
from ..demo import sayHello
```

Let me know the correct way of importing

```
app 
    demo.py
    __init__.py

    **Controllers**
    AccountController.py
    __init__.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in python it's best to use the relative path within the project. (Based on the question, I can't tell where you're trying to use the imported function, but I'm assuming it's within the same project)

Packages like os, sys etc are built within your Python executable, so those are available globally. Anything else needs to be relative.