# Python: Can't import a function from parent directory

Tags: python, testing

If I have the following directory structure:

Folder1/
└─ Folder2/
──── a.py
──── b.py
└─── test/
────── c.py

a.py

```
import b

def say_hello():
    print("Hello World")

def main():
    say_hello()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

b.py

```
def say_bye():
    print('bye!')
```

c.py

```
from hello import a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a.say_hello()
```

I'm trying to run c.py
But I get this error message:

```
    import b
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python import module from parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250058/python-import-module-from-parent-package)

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057464/relative-importing-modules-from-parent-folder-subfolder) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825474/python-import-module-from-a-parent-directory)

Answer (score 0):

if a and b are in the same directory add before the import:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

this will add the relative folder to path.